# Which behaviour should I expect of the extended KALMAN FILTER covariance?

Tags: filter, system, theory, kalman-filter

I have an extended kalman filter setting, which converges to the reference value pretty well. However, if i check the covariance matrix I cannot see a fast trend to a certain value of the diagonal elements (3x3), which is actually what I expected.

How should the covariance matrix behave? Can somebody give me a hint on that?

Answer (score 0):

The diagonal elements will increase in the prediction/propagation step by the process noise that is applied there. In the measurement/correction step, the diagonal elements should go down. If this is not the case, either your measurement noise is too large or the process noise noise is too large. In that case the noise added in the prediction step increases the covariance more than the measurements reduce them. At some point, there will be a balance between the two.

Of course your model or implementation could also be wrong....

Comment: Which would mean that Q has to be somewhat smaller than the reduction of the innovation process?

Comment: Is there a breakpoint until which I can increase Q while keeping P convergent?

Comment: In all but the simplest cases this is not completely true. The variance of one state does not only increase by Q, but also by the propagation of the variances of the other states. Example: a 2 state filter estimating position and velocity (x, v). The next x is calculated by x + v*dt The variance of the position will increase not only by Q_x, but also by the variance in v.